# How do I complete the Destroyer of Destiny achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Destroyer of Destiny requires that you destroy all 4 Activated Pillars in the Royal Crypt at once. This can obviously only be done when going to face the Skeleton King.

The pillars are placed a fairly good distance apart and all of the AOE or AOE-like attacks that I have tried with either the Monk or Demon Hunter have failed to destroy all 4 pillars. Replaying the section from when the Templar joins up to the pillars is getting tedious and I'm really at a loss.

What character/attack/strategy should I use? Is this something where you need a 4-player co-op to achieve it or something (exact timing on this would be bananas)?

Comment: This isn't very practical but worth a try if you are getting frustrated - The [levelup explosion](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66420/5291) is pretty large, it might do the trick.

Comment: @dpatchery Nope. That did not work unfortunately and might I say that the getting that set up just to try it was a pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Monk's [Seven-Sided Strike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/sevensided-strike) right in the middle:

[image: "Destroyer of Destiny"]

Comment: This worked for me and at level much lower than 60. I would like to see strategies for all classes, but as it stands, this is a very easy way to get this achievement.

Comment: Wizard's forceful push from the center, and Demon Hunter's Multishot aimed from the corner of one pillar towards the center (so the shots fan out and hit the others) can also work.

Answer (score 8):

I did it as a Wizard using Disintegrate with the Chaos Nexus rune. Just stood in the middle and fired the beam in a random direction, Chaos Nexus did the rest. I was lvl 37 at the time, with about 660 dps.

Comment: Leveling a new character of a different class up to ~37 will take a while. I would prefer a solution with the characters I have or, even better, an answer that covers this achievement for each class. It will take me a while to test this as the correct answer and I'm sort of holding out to see if someone will come up with a better answer to fit my/all classes.

Answer (score 3):

Use Rain of Vengeance as a Demon Hunter

Answer (score 2):

Spike trap with bandolier worked. Place before any of them "come alive".

Answer (score 2):

I used the wizard 'Wave of Force' ability with the 'Force Affinity' rune, stood between all four, waited for them to activate and killed them all down by using Wave of Force once.

Demon Hunter can use Rain of Vengeance to achieve this equally as straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Demon Hunter - Place 3 Caltrops with Jagged Spikes rune on 3 of the pillars. Use Vault with Trail of Cinders Rune on 4th. When all 4 pillars become active they get destroyed at the same time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with Demon HUnter by using STRAFE with throwing knives perk. Just before Leoric finished his speech, I started the ability and did it. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use rain of vengeance without any rune, that should do it!

Answer (score 1):

For Witch Doctors, your Locust Swarm ability should do the trick. Just keep casting it as the pillars activate and they should die pretty much instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Crusader is not an ideal class to achieve this, I was able to complete it with my Crusader.

It was easy after coordinating the timing of two skills: Condemn and Bombardment. I used the Shattering Explosion rune for Condemn and the Impactful Bombardment rune for Bombardment to increase radius to 20 and 18 yards just to have the widest AoE. Unfortunately the 20 yard radius of Condemn is still not enough to get all 4 pillars with just this one skill.

I moved myself to be within range of the lower two pillars and left my cursor between the upper two pillars, cast Condemn, then a quick 3 seconds later I cast Bombardment. Hit all four pillars at the same time.

You'd think having the rune to make Condemn instant would help, but it just makes it more challenging.

Answer (score -1):

If you're a Witch doctor, use the lumbering cold rune for Zombie charger from the center.