# What is the range and power of the level up blast in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

As explained in [Does leveling up do damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66420/1770), a damaging blast explodes from your body when you level up in Diablo 3.  What is the range and damage potential of this blast? Does the blast grow stronger as you level up?

Answer (score 1):

The range of the blast is 50(in game) yards , As for the how much damage is does not a clue

Comment: What is your source?